# Reloading/Restarting Vite Server from within server process

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I need to add some custom business logic to my Vite/Svelte app that requires the Vite server to be restarted. I see that there's a keyboard shortcut `r` that does exactly this, however I can't determine if the function behind this can be called separately. For example restart the server on a specific day of the week. Ideally it would also be good to trigger this restart programmatically from outside of my Vite/Svelte app process.

Is any of this possible ?

Comment: If it's your own server, you may use node adapter managed with pm2. you should be able to cron with it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a difference between reload and restart. In my case reloading was not enough, I needed to restart the app completely (here to restart when a `.grammar` file is changed):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import {lezer} from "@lezer/generator/rollup"

// Watch .grammar files
function grammarwatch() {
  return {
    name: 'grammarwatch',
    enforce: 'post',
    // HMR
    handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
      if (file.endsWith('.grammar')) {
        console.log('reloading grammar file...');
        // To restart
        server.restart()
        // To reload
        /* server.ws.send({
         *   type: 'full-reload',          
         *   path: '*'
         * }); */
      }
    },
  }
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    lezer(),
    grammarwatch()
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Vite server is for development *only*.

How the final application can be restarted depends on where you want to deploy/[adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters) being used to build the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [vite-plugin-restart](https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-restart) plugin.

This [example config](https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-restart/blob/main/examples/vanilla/vite.config.ts) will restart the server when there are any changes to the trigger file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import ViteRestart from 'vite-plugin-restart'

{
  // ...
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), ViteRestart({ 
      restart: ['./trigger.txt'] 
    })]
}
```

You can use a `await writeFile('./trigger.txt', '')` from your code, or do an `echo > trigger.txt` from the terminal to trigger a restart.